# Unable to add in new user to Firebase after the alert box?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a register user page and saving it into Firebase.

My form includes first name, last name, email, password and confirm password.

I am able to create a new object into my Firebase Database, but when I added the if else statement to make sure the password and confirm password matches, it keeps on giving me:

> "Uncaught Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'projectdatabase.password' error."

after the alert box.

It works fine if password and confirm password matches. How can I solve this error?

```
  if(firebase.apps.length===0){
     firebase.initializeApp(config);

     var sFName = document.getElementById("sfname").value;
     var sLName = document.getElementById("slname").value;
     var sEmail = document.getElementById("semail").value;

     if((document.getElementById("spassword").value)==(document.getElementById("sconfirmpassword").value)){
     var sPassword = document.getElementById("spassword").value;

         var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('projectdatabase');
         //store the data in Javascript object
         var postData = {
            firstname : sFName,
            lastname : sLName,
            email : sEmail,
            password : sPassword
         };

         dbRef.push(postData);
         document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 
         "Registered!"

     } else{
        alert("Re-Enter confirm password!") 
         var sFName = document.getElementById("sfname").value;
         var sLName = document.getElementById("slname").value;
         var sEmail = document.getElementById("semail").value;

         if((document.getElementById("spassword").value)==(document.getElementById("sconfirmpassword").value)){
            var sPassword = document.getElementById("spassword").value;
             var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('projectdatabase');

             var postData = {
                firstname : sFName,
                lastname : sLName,
                email : sEmail,
                password : sPassword
             };

             dbRef.push(postData);
             document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 
             "Registered!"
        }
     }


  }
```

Comment: Please provide more information if you expect us to help you. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem is pretty much what the error says: the value in the `sPassword` variable must be `undefined`.

Comment: @cartant is there any ways that I can prompt the user to re-enter password and confirm password (make sure it matches) and save it into the "database" after the user typed in an unmatched password?